# Concat multiple rows based on If/Then to poulate a 5 digit code

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, concatenation

Hoping someone can help.

I have data as follows in two seperate columns in a table called StudentRace

```
Student_ID    RaceCD
----------    ------
123456        1 
123456        2
589645        4
987654        3
987654        4
```

I am looking for a way to combine the data for the students by student id to output into 00000 format. example: Student_ID 123456 RACE: 12000; Student_ID 589645 Race: 00040; Student_ID 987654  Race = 00340. I need to have it be a sub query as it is part of a large report that pulls 50+ fields. If anyone is able to help I would greatly appreciate it. I am using Toads Data Point for Oracle to create my query.

Answer (score 5):

The result can be achieved with a single group by without any joins.

#### Setup

```
CREATE TABLE studentrace
(
    Student_ID,
    RaceCD
)
AS
    SELECT 123456, 1 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456, 2 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 589645, 4 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, 3 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 987654, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

#### Query

```
  SELECT student_id, LPAD (SUM (racecd * POWER (10, 5 - racecd)), 5, '0') AS race
    FROM studentrace
GROUP BY student_id;
```

#### Result

```
   STUDENT_ID     RACE
_____________ ________
       589645 00040
       987654 00340
       123456 12000
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly by itself. I then added it as a sub query to the larger query that I am doing and received an : ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: thank you I had to add where sr.studentid = s.id to make it work in my larger query. YOU ROCK!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a partitioned outer join:

```sql
SELECT t.Student_id,
       LISTAGG( COALESCE( t.raceCD, 0 ) ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY r.race )
         AS RaceCDs
FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL AS race
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 ) r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t
       PARTITION BY ( t.Student_ID )
       ON ( r.race = t.RaceCD )
GROUP BY t.student_id
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Student_ID, RaceCD ) AS
SELECT 123456, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 589645, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 987654, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 987654, 4 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> STUDENT_ID | RACECDS
> ---------: | :------
>     123456 | 12000  
>     589645 | 00040  
>     987654 | 00340
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c3af98a3f0708f4606cde03ad24c360)*

Comment: the value is stored as a number in the table with the query that you provided it is expecting a char so it is kicking an error.

Comment: @JessicaRoos Use `TO_NUMBER` to convert a string to a number.